# How can I start periodical actions server side?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to develop a react/redux application and I want to run some server code without needing to trigger an action client side. Right now my needs are to calculate and storage some info in the database and i don't want to run a client that triggers a server action, but in the future i want to make some automatic changes in the database everyday to update my database information based on my previous information. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is called a cron-job.

Comment: If the data you want to store in the database comes from the client-side, then you need to trigger the action from client-side, otherwise, you can use the server Cron Jobs, which triggers the URL after the specified time.

Comment: no, de data I need to trigger the action is alredy contained in the data base, i just want to update the database information based on the information i alredy have, and do it periodically. Just like if i want everyday to truncate a database table cause i don't want to preserve it and i want to do it server side, cause client side doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called a cronjob. The implementation of this depends mostly on your hosting, but the syntax is always pretty much the same. Let's say you have a file called `cron.php` which contains the logic for your automatic changes.

The cronjob would look something like this:

```
0 0 * * * location/to/cron.php
```

The first two numbers mean at 0 minutes and 0 hours (so 00:00), the following stars mean every day, every month and every weekday. More information about cronjobs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and [here](https://crontab-generator.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Start a cron-job script executing WGET command for open you web page, or directly call your script.

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/youraction
```

in a cron job:

```
*/5 * * * * wget --quiet -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/youraction
```

here you can find a guide about edit your cron jobs
https://www.lifewire.com/crontab-linux-command-4095300